# Azure Function 2 - missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: azure-functions, .net-assembly

I created my Azure Function v2 using Visual Studio 2017.

I created a new Queue Trigger function.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Functions
{
    public static class queue
    {
        [FunctionName("queue")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "test")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

But the assembly of QueueTrigger could not be found

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'QueueTriggerAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'QueueTrigger' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Connection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: I would suggest rechecking the docs to make sure you configured everything correctly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#packages---functions-2x

Comment: There's a bug on Visual Studio 2017.
When I create a new Azure Function Project with a blank option. This bug happens.

But if I create using some template, this bug doesn't happen.

Comment: It's a little sad that this is still not fixed as of the latest VS 2019 update dated 9/21/2020. As I understand it, these templates come with the core VS updates now as opposed to a separate tool/extension update, unless anyone knows different? Just trying to determine where to report this.

Comment: Install these packages here saved me https://stackoverflow.com/a/61493781/5937760

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Nkosi said, you could go to [Azure Queue storage bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#packages---functions-2x) to check if you have configure binding extensions.

For your info, I think you need to install [`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage) NuGet package, version 3.x. Then everything will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I created a queue trigger function in Visual studio code using cli tools. It created azure function with version 2.0 in host.json file. When I run the function I got the same error. I could resolve this by adding below lines in .csproj file.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
```