# “The type or namespace ‘BlobTrigger’ could not be found”

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, compiler-errors, azure-functions

So I'm new to Azure functions in C# and I'm trying to create on in Visual Studio with a BlobStorage Trigger. While following the template, I was given a file that looks something like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Triggers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace BasicAzureFunction
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

I always get this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'BlobTriggerAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm pretty sure I have all the packages (this is literally the template). What am I missing?

Using .Net Core

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this all the code you have in the project of the Azure Function?

Comment: Yes, other than the local.settings.json and host.json file, but I didn't touch those

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have an Azure Function that also uses a BlobTrigger and it's working correctly for me.

I have this namespace that I don't see in the code you shared

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

and I have these Nuget packages in my project

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The current recommended way is installing `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs` instead of the metapackage `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage`

From the [Azure WebJobs Storage ReadMe](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage_5.0.1/sdk/storage/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/README.md):

> This extension provides functionality for accessing Azure Storage Blobs and Queues in Azure Functions. This package is a metapackage created for backwards compatibity. Using `Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs` and `Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues` directly is recommended.

Note that an in-process model needs a different set of packages from an isolated model

In-process package:
`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs`

Isolated package:
`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs`

so in a `dotnet-isolated` function app we end up with the following packages in our .csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="5.0.0" />
```